# How to avoid QNetworkRequest to send the RHELP verb to the FTP Server?

Tags: c++, qt, ftp, ftp-client

**The Scenario:** 
I'm implementing an **FTP get** functionality in my application, that uses **Qt 4.7.x** 
Qt documentation states that the **QFtp** class **is deprecated**, to use  QNetworkAccessManager instead, and so I'm doing ;) 
 I tested the code I wrote with some FTP server out there and it seems to work fine.

**The Problem:** 
When I connect to my local, homebrewed (and quite simple), ftp server using my ftp get class I get the following error: **Request: 500 No Help Available.**
I traced the ftp communication using *tcpdump* and actually I see that the *QNetworkAccessManager/QNetworkRequest* sends an **HELP** verb to the server, once it gets the **230 User Logged In**

Unfortunately my server do not support that. Now is there a way to configure the Qt not to send the HELP verb? Reading the Qt Doc online for the involved classes did not helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably no way to avoid this, unless you want to reimplement the FTP backend. By browsing the [source code for the FTP backend](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/network/access/qnetworkaccessftpbackend.cpp), you can find out that the purpose for sending the `HELP` command is to find out if the server supports the "SIZE" and "MDTM" commands.

Probably the easiest solution would be to implement a minimal handler for HELP commands in your FTP server that responds with an appropriate 200/211/214 response.

EDIT: See http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/network/access/qnetworkaccessftpbackend.cpp#line350 for what the backend expects from the response. It's not complicated.

Comment: Should not it be a 211 rather than 214? Anyhow that's not the main point... point is I will have to implement the HELP :-/

Comment: If you don't support SIZE and MDTM in your server, it doesn't really matter... if you do, it has to be either 200 or 214. I'll edit my response.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I do support SIZE actually. But I'm still a bit confused: The FTP RFC states that:  **211** System status, or system help reply  **214** Help message. On how to use the server or the meaning of a particular non-standard command. This reply is useful only to the human user. That's why I was thinking I need a 211 code.

Comment: Well the list of commands returned by the HELP command with no parameters is meant for human readers, thus it is returned in a 214. The backend just sees if that list of commands contains SIZE or MDTM. It smells a bit like a non-standard hack, but maybe that was the simplest solution they could come up with.

Comment: for the record, I added the HELP command to my ftp server as suggested (also by @vipw) and I'm now able to get the files off my FTP server with my Qt class. Thanks to both of you :)

Answer (score 3):

It is not configurable.
You can see the source code of what's happening here: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/network/access/qnetworkaccessftpbackend.cpp#line300

If you can build your own version of Qt, then it can easily be suppressed. But it might be easier for you to upgrade your FTP server to support the HELP command.